# SQL multiple columns value multiplications

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I want to multiply 2 columns in a single table the thing is one column is in the table but the other one is  calculated.

My table structure :

```
cart_id(pk)    pro_id(fk)    pro_name    pro_price
```

My query is:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(pro_id) AS ID 
FROM cart  
WHERE session_id='" . $_SESSION['session'] . "'
GROUP BY pro_id;
```

Now I want to calculate product price (pro_price) multiply ID which does not exist but calculated by product counts (count(pro_id)AS ID ).

Comment: Please do not repost questions.

Comment: I asked different question using same table .

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select pro_id, sum(pro_price)
from cart
where session_id='" . $_SESSION['session'] . "'
group by pro_id
```

if the price is equal for all carts with identical pro_id, then sum(pro_price) equals count(*) * pro_price.